# How to change form parameters when user trying to submit the specified form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there any way to change form parameters when user trying to submit the specified form?

Suppose that I have the following form:

```
<form id="myform" method="port" action="/form.php">
  <input type="file" name="image1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So when the user clicks a submit button it makes a POST request to the `/form.php` that contains `image1` parameter. I want to change this parameter to completely different base64-encoded image programmatically.

Is it possible?

Comment: this would really help you [Image to base64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/image-convert-to-base64)

Comment: @ksno I don't want to convert the user-provided image to its base64 analogue, I want to change the corresponding form parameter to completely different base64-encoded image

Comment: maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) would help

Comment: @FrozenHeart [and this is an example how you would convert text (the value of `image1` parameter for e.g.) to image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875638/how-to-convert-text-into-image-using-jquery), which can then be converted to base64-encoded image with example above `:)`

Comment: @ArchLicher No, it just tells how to make base64-encoding for image while I'm asking how to change form parameter programmatically

Comment: @ksno I'm asking how to change form parameter programmatically

Comment: Can explain furthermore what r u trying to achieve, please?

Comment: what is parameter? name of input field or value of it? `$('form').find('input').attr('name', 'newName');` for name and `$('form').find('input').attr('value', 'newValue');` for value. Question seems unclear to me.

Comment: @ArchLicher Edited

Comment: @ksno Edited, see OP-post

Comment: Do you need to send an image or a base-64 string ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle I need to send an image encoded as a base64 string

Comment: Then you can just modify your `<input>` attributes/values using JS ? Just give it an ID to ease the thing :)

Comment: @PinkTurtle I don't think so. `$('#image1').val('data:image/png;base64,alotoftext')` resulting in the following error -- "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string"

Comment: Did you try changing the input type instead ? `$.("#image1").type = "text";` then change it's value ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle Uncaught Error: type property can't be changed

Comment: Well then you're stuck with `file` typed input which can't be a string. Here is your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the values in jQuery's `$('form').submit()` event, as described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547963/5742681

You can replace the form values with anything you want, by creating a new data object and `POST`ing that instead of the original form values.

If you don't want to use jQuery's .`post()` for some reason, you can also change the input values in `$('form').submit()` and return true, the standard submit event will happen after jQuery's.

Comment: Yes, I know it but I wonder is there any way to change the values of **exisiting** submit action? I don't want to construct a POST request from scratch by myself.

Comment: This answer is correct. Although I would avoid overriding the form submit event for clarity reasons (it won't be clear from just the HTML that the form does something except a POST). I would add a general button linking onClick to a JavaScript function where I would implement base-64 encoding and a POST request. Just something to consider.

Comment: It seems that I can't just change the input values in case of `<input type="file">` tag. It gives me the following error -- "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string"

Answer (score 0):

Add ID to your file input and a hidden input field so html looks like:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="/form.php">
  <input id="changeme" type="file" name="image1">
  <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="base64img" value="">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In jQuery you would take some actions on form submit like:

```
var frm = $('#myform');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
   frm.find('input#hidden').attr('value', 'data:image/png;base64,alotoftext');
   frm.find('input#changeme').remove();
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you dont have access to server, add elemt with jQuery like:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'hidden',
    name: 'base64img',
    value: ''
}).appendTo('#myform');
```

Comment: I don't have an access to the server side, so it can't just be an another element

Comment: @FrozenHeart did you try add an input field with jQuery as in edited answer suggested?